# Is there a better way to fetch OpenID infos from provider?

Tags: php, cakephp, openid

I am new to the OpenID logic. I am using the OpenID component for CakePHP by Cakebaker, with the PHP OpenID library by JanRain.

It's all working quite well, but I could not find an exhaustive way to retrieve user informations depending on provider and method (sreg vs. ax). So this is what I came up with:

```
if ($axResponse) {
    if (is_array($a = $axResponse->get('http://axschema.org/contact/email'))) {
        $user_record['email'] = $a[0];
        if (is_array($b = $axResponse->get('http://axschema.org/namePerson'))) {
            $user_record['nickname'] = $b[0];
        }
    } else if (is_array($a = $axResponse->get('http://schema.openid.net/contact/email'))) {
        $user_record['email'] = $a[0];
        if (is_array($b = $axResponse->get('http://schema.openid.net/namePerson'))) {
            $user_record['nickname'] = $b[0];
        }
    }
} else if ($sreg) {
    if (isset($sreg['email'])) {
        $user_record['email'] = $sreg['email'];
    }
    if (isset($sreg['nickname'])) {
        $user_record['nickname'] = $sreg['nickname'];
    }
}
```

Although I tested it successfully with Google, Yahoo! and AOL's OpenID, I'm sure I would run into trouble with other / smaller providers. Is there a better and nicer way to achieve the same result? This seems particularly flawed if I try to fetch other optional fields...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep in mind that OpenID is a standard for user authentication, not for authorization for data access. You can, naturally, get certain user info using OpenID, but it's not the protocol's primary intent. OAuth is the standard for authorization and you might want to start with that, if fetching user data is what you need.

Comment: I totally agree with you, so far as to close this question and accept your answer. Luckily, things have evolved quite a bit since then, with OAuth2 gaining support, and nowadays, I would only use it, and be done with OpenID for most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am sorry... i don't know much about the "OpenID component for CakePHP", but i have worked  with the **lightopenid** and it is opensource also..

Check this out:
http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/updates/list

I have worked with this many times.. and it is good.. I hope this helps...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help me much, as everything already works fine. I'm more looking for an elegant way to deal with the response, which isn't covered by this library and its documentation either...

Comment: Theoretically, you could just copy the `get*Attributes()` functions from LightOpenID, substituting `$this->data` -> `$_GET + $_POST`.

Comment: I have to say this looks like a fine Library, but I wish I could keep mine as it already cost me some time. Also, I find it weird that you achieve so much with so much less code than the JanRain library!